# USB C Host mode and charging

Tags: usb, charging

Is it possible for a USB C device in the device role to charge the host?  Can this be accomplished with resistors or does it need a USB PD IC?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. It's described in the USB PD standard.

To achieve it, the devices must communicate on the CC lines using the USB PD protocol. So it cannot be achieved with resistors only. It requires a USB PD controller of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the **host is a power supplier**, and the **device is a power consumer**.

If I understood correctly, you want the host to be the power consumer without losing the host role. There's only one way of achieving this: as stated in @Codo's answer, VDM (Vendor-Defined Messaging) through CC lines. It's quite complex to implement by yourself but some PD controllers already support this. You may want to take a look at [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/technical_article/dm00496853-overview-of-usb-type-c-and-power-delivery-technologies-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

Comment: Power role swap is fully defined by USB PD and does not involve any VDM. VDM is used for other things.

Comment: Can you suggest a PD which supports that?

Comment: @MehmetFide Suggest a PD controller chip? Or suggest a PD device that implements it?

Comment: I meant a chip actually